# How to avoid column name conflicts in cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hector

I need to store a list of user names in a Cassandra column family(wide row/dynamic columns).
The columnname/comparator type will be integer, so as to sort the users based on a score.
The score ranges from 0 to 100. The problem is, if two or more users have a same score, how can i store them on different columns?, as cassandra would not allow that...
Is there any way to convert integer to timeuuids? Or any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem I have seen quite often (not scores but preventing column name conflict). In general the solution is a form or another of concatenating a UUID to the column name (Since those are made to never conflict).

If you want to keep on sorting by score then I advice you to use a CompositeType column name.
More specifically:

`CompositeType(score: Integer | time: TimeUUID)`

The comparator in Cassandra will then first sort by score and then by time (putting the most recent last I believe).
TimeUUID should also take care of "simultaneous" score posting even thought the probabilities to have that with a Long timestamp would be ridiculously low.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build-in list feature, see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections
Just have column with a value and list of users for that value.